# How do I add/replace a value in column B if column A contains the searched word

Tags: excel

I want to do the following using Excel :

In column `AX` it have a long description, and I want to find the text `5.0-Rated.png` from it, and then add `5.0 out of 5.0 stars` to column `AY` which currently have the values of 0.

I want to add that to the whole column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, place in `AY1` and drag down as you like

```
=MID(AX1,SEARCH("?.?-rated.png",AX1),3)&" out of 5.0 stars"
```

---

Note: it will throw a `#VALUE!` error if there is no such filename in the string. You can avoid that by wrapping the whole formula in an `IFERROR` function like this:

```
=IFERROR(MID(AX1,SEARCH("?.?-rated.png",AX1),3)&" out of 5.0 stars","")
```

---

Working like so: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, its working but I forgot to mention something, i need to also add on the same column more replacement such as `4.9 out of 5.0 stars` etc.. Right now i am only getting one name change.

Comment: I added an image of the formula in action. Is that not how you expect it to function? -- if not you might need to explain the problem a bit further

Comment: The problem is, i want to select the same column everytime i am done with a rating, because if i do that my other text that already have been added will get deleted and be replaced with the new text.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. Can you add an image to your question to illustrate this?

Comment: If i used the code `=IFERROR(MID(AX1,SEARCH("4.9-rated.png",AX1),3)&" out of 4.9 stars","")` for example and i wanted to add the remaining ratings such as `=IFERROR(MID(AX1,SEARCH("4.8-rated.png",AX1),3)&" out of 4.8 stars","")`, my first work that i have done which is the 4.9 stars will get deleted when i grab the code down to the cells.

So i only get 4.9 as a rating or whatever rating i choose.

http://i.imgur.com/VlKp5fu.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/Y0wEw5J.jpg

Comment: I think you need to keep the question marks in the formula I gave you. `SEARCH("?.?-rated...)` needs the `?.?` not `5.0` or similar

Comment: Oh.. yeah, your right. Now its working perfectly. I thought i had to do that my own self.

Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help